# Checking multiple variables for value change

Tags: javascript

I have 6 variables (Lets call them var1, var2,...). They all have predefined initial values. In the course of my program, their values may get redefined. (I have an option to either overwrite the values or store the new values in separate variables) At the end of a particular function, I need to do something only if any of the values have changed from their initial values.

I am trying to avoid writing a long if statement for that task like:

```
if ((var1 != var1new) || (var2 != var2new)......)
{
    //do something...
}
```

Any ideas to do this elegantly?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are they numbers or strings?

Comment: @VivinPaliath They are all integers.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in an object and loop through it:

```
var values = { var1: { current: 0, initital: 0 }, var2: { current: 0, initial : 0 } };

for(var v in values)
{
    if(v.current !== v.initial)
    {
        //Changed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store them inside a map:

```
var vars = {
    original: {
        var1: ...,
        var2: ...,
        ...
    },
    updated: {
        var1: ...,
        var2: ...,
        ...
    }
};
```

You'd end up writing the updated values to `vars.updated` (so `vars.updated.var1`) for example.

After that you can simply loop over to detect if anything has changed.

```
var changed = false;
var keys = Object.keys(vars.original);
var i = 0;

while(!changed && i < keys.length) {
    var key = keys[i];
    changed = (vars.original[key] !== vars.updated[key]);
    i++;
}
```

You can also do it in a more functional way using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var similar = Object.keys(vars.original).reduce(function(similar, key) {
    return similar && (vars.original[key] === vars.updated[key]);
}, true);
```

It's more elegant than looping. Note that this tells you if the objects *haven't* changed (the `while` above tells you if they *have* changed).

Comment: @Jim, I don't follow. As soon as it detects an inequality, `changed` becomes `true`, which means the loop will bail out immediately.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't notice the !changed in the WHILE. That's why I deleted my comment ;-).